# Magento Create Category Tree Structure

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-tree

I am working on script which is used in outside of magento. I am using this [link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/14/magento-generate-category-tree-recursively/) for creating category tree structure but it gives me only those category collection which are active in admin section for particular store. It not gives me other categories which are active in subadmin panel but inactive in admin panel. I want all active category tree structure on the basis of subadmin active condition on categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('1');
$collection= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('id')
->addAttributeToSelect('parent_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('position')
->addAttributeToSelect('level')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');
echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>id</th>";
    echo "<th>name</th>";
    echo "<th>parent</th>";
    echo "<th>is_active</th>";
    echo "<th>position</th>";
    echo "<th>level</th>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach($collection as $col)
{
    echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getId()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getName()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getParentId()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getIsActive()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getPosition()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$col->getLevel()."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

**Edited the Demo for you**

```
  <?php
    $rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
    function  get_categories($categories) {
        $array= '<ul>';
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
if ($cat->getIsActive()) {

            $count = $cat->getProductCount();
            $array .= '<li>'.
            '<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">' .
                      $category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
            if($category->hasChildren()) {
                $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
                 $array .=  get_categories($children);
                }
             $array .= '</li>';
        }
}
        return  $array . '</ul>';
    }
    echo  get_categories($categories); ?>
```

Comment: It provides Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection::getStoreCategories()

Comment: is flat categories are enabled ?

Comment: no it is not enabled.

Comment: Sorry My bad , edited my Answer

Comment: again same error

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar getStoreCategories is defined in Mage::helper('catalog/category')

Comment: Any one know how can i change demo link. Becasue it is working just only not getting store wise collection.

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar you're now calling load once per category. You could take the output of getChildren and pass it to a category collection using `addIdFilter`

Comment: Above code not generate tree as according to my requirement.

Comment: @Richard Do post the Answer you are suggesting, mathew Check the demo edit code now

Comment: you requirement was to filter the inactive categories , its doing that what is not fulfiled now ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you are outside magento call Mage file in your current file, then you can use all models of magento.

Use bellow code to show all categories, the bellow code is showing me 3 level categories:

```
 <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php //$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

<?php
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($currentCat != '') {
        $categoryp = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId());
        $path = $categoryp->getPath();  

        $ids = explode('/', $path);
    $var_id = $currentCat->getId();
} 


?>
<?php $m = 0; ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul >
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): $m++; ?>

            <li class="<?php if ($var_id == ($_category->getId())) {
                echo 'active';
            } ?>" >

            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/menu_icon_' . $m . '.png'); ?>" alt="">
            <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>

            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>                    
                <ul>                            
                    <li>
                        <div class="submenu_area">
                            <div class="categorys">
                                <ul id="inner_category">
                                    <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                    <?php
                                        //echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId())->getThumbnail();
                                    ?>
                                    <?php $_subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>

                                    <?php $_subsubcategories = $_subcategory->getChildrenCategories() ;?>
                                    <?php $subcount = $_subsubcategories->count(); ?>
                                    <li class="<?php if($subcount < 1){echo 'nochild';}?><?php if(isset($ids[3]) && ($ids[3] == $_subcategory->getId() or $ids[2] == $_subcategory->getId()) ){echo 'current';}?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php if($subcount > 0 ){?>
                                        <ul> 
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="subcategory_labels">
                                                    <div class="subcategory_menu">
                                                    <h2><?php echo $_subcategory->getName(); ?> </h2>
                                                        <!--sub sub category-->
                                                    <?php

                                                    if ($subcount > 4) {
                                                        $CatPerColumn = ceil($subcount / 4);
                                                    } else {
                                                        $CatPerColumn = 1;
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <?php $i = 1;
                                                    if (count($_subsubcategories) > 0): ?>
                                                        <?php foreach ($_subsubcategories as $_subsubcategory): ?>    
                                                              <?php if (($i - 1) % $CatPerColumn == 0): ?>
                                                            <div class="subcat_menus_list">
                                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                                            <!--sub fourth sub category-->
                                                            <?php $_subcategoryfou = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subsubcategory->getId()) ?>
                                                            <?php $_subsubcategoriesfou = $_subcategoryfou->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
                                                            <?php if ($_subsubcategoriesfou->getSize() >  0) { ?>
                                                                <h4>
                                                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory) ?>">
                                                                        <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName() ?>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </h4>
                                                            <?php  }else{ ?>
                                                                <h4 class="hsmall">
                                                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory) ?>">
                                                                        <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName() ?>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </h4>
                                                            <?php }  ?>
                                                            <?php if (count($_subsubcategoriesfou) > 0): ?>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <?php foreach ($_subsubcategoriesfou as $_subsubcategory): ?>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory) ?>">
                                                                         <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName() ?>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </li> 

                                                                <?php endforeach; ?>   
                                                            </ul>

                                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                            <!--sub sub category-->

                                                            <?php if ($i % $CatPerColumn == 0 Or $i == $subcount): ?>
                                                            </div><?php endif; ?>
                                                            <?php $i++;
                                                        endforeach; ?>           
                                                    <?php endif; ?>                                 
                                                    <div class="clr"></div>
                                                </div>


                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                         </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>

                            </div>


                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>    
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


    </ul>
```

Comment: Where did you checked if the category is enabled or disabled

Comment: this is for all active/inactive categories, if you need use this code  <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>